# C# and writing HTML - best way?

Tags: c#, browser, htmltextwriter

I would need to build a HTML document from plain text and display it in webBrowser. I was thinking of better way - I can see there is HTMLTextWriter in System.Web.UI but I cannot reference this namespace, could anyone advice?
Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue and created a MIT-licensed library for just this. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776837/973813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your application requirements you could host your own browser control and build the content:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser _browser = new WebBrowser();
_browser.DocumentText = "<html><head><title>My Web Page</title></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use plain `XmlWriter` (or, if you need more complex building than just writing a stream of elements, `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`) and output XHTML.

If you want to use `System.Web.UI` classes, you need to reference `System.Web.dll` from your project. I wouldn't recommend it, though, as it won't buy you much, and it is not included in the .NET Client Profile (which you might want to use in the future, especially with .NET 4).

Comment: Thanks! Is that capable of writing html header etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by HTML header? If `<head>`, then it is an XHTML element like any other, and, naturally, can be written easily.