# Generating HTML page in C# - Best practices

Tags: c#, html

I have to generate a big html page in my C# code (It's not a site, just a big single-page html report)

Page contains a different sections compiled in one page. Each section contains CSS styles, javascript parts and body related to it. CSS style are static parts, script & body parts are generated using a different input data (csv text).

My first artless solution to simplify all-in-one generation is to create a builder function:

```
 private static string BuildHtmlPage(string[] cssParts, string[] scriptParts, string[] bodyParts)
    {
        var htmlPage = "";
        htmlPage += @"<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>";

htmlPage += "\n<head>";

        htmlPage += "\n<style>\n";
            foreach (var cssPart in cssParts)
            {
                htmlPage += cssPart +"\n";
            }
        htmlPage += "</style>\n";

        htmlPage += @"<script type=""text/javascript"">";
        htmlPage += "window.onload = function() {";

            foreach (var scriptPart in scriptParts)
            {
                htmlPage += scriptPart + "\n";
            }

        htmlPage += @"}
</script>";

htmlPage += "\n</head>";

        htmlPage += "\n<body>\n";
            foreach (var bodyPart in bodyParts)
            {
                htmlPage += bodyPart + "\n";
            }
        htmlPage += "\n</body>";

htmlPage += "\n</html>";

return htmlPage;

    }
```

Then to generate a "small" html parts and use it like this:

```
var htmlResult = BuildHtmlPage(
            new [] {style1, style2 },
            new [] {script1, script2, script3 },
            new [] {body1, body2, body3 }
        );
```

It made my code a little cleaner, but it still looks ugly and hard maintainable because of a lot of html code mixed into C# code.

What ideas to handle such task could you suggest? First, I mean separation of html code from C#.

Comment: have a look at razor. theres embedable forms of it

Comment: You can also try to make a page with fixed content and scripts, and try to format the data using javascript.

Comment: I concur with the razor suggestion. As an alternate approach: while not all HTML is valid XML, you *can* build HTML like valid XML and thus make use of XML libraries like LINQ to XML. -- also, if the resulting HTML doesn't need to be read by a human, remove all unnecessary formatting, like spaces or linebreaks.

Comment: If you are not going to go the Razor way, at least use a `StringBuilder` rather than concatenating strings

Comment: I think you've answered your question yourself. IMHO, it looks like you're reinventing the wheel whereas the approach would/should be something like "how do I present large amounts of data in a UI"?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a very clean approach which will empower you with all the functionality you get from a web application, Visual Studio formatting of HTML, Razor (basically everything within an MVC project):

1. Create an ASP.NET MVC project.
2. Create your view as if you were creating an MVC view.
3. Once you are happy with the look and feel then create another application (Console, Windows Forms etc.) and reference the MVC application from it.
4. Instead of using the browser, the console application can get the view from the MVC application.

Hereinafter, I am going to assume we have a console application which will use the MVC application.

**Steps To Configure MVC Application**

These steps will pre-compile your views. Thus later we will be able to access the views directly from the console application.

1. Right click your MVC project and add these NuGet packages:

   1. [RazorGenerator.MsBuild](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/wiki/Using-RazorGenerator.MsBuild)
   2. [RazorGenerator.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc/)
2. Open your MVC project's `.csproj` file in notepad and add these elements:

   1.In the topmost `PropertyGroup` element, add `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`

   2.At the very end of the file add:

   ```
   <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
       <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
   </Target>
   ```

   3.Build the project. We need to make sure the views are compiled. To make sure it is actually being compiled, in the `.cshtml` file write some code that does not compile. When you compile, if everything has been setup properly, the compilation should fail indicating that the compiler is compiling the views also. If it does not fail, then one of the above steps was not done as specified. If it fails, good news. Remove the error and compile again.

**Steps to Configure the Console Application**

1. Right click the project and add the [RazorGenerator.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Testing/). Even though we are not testing, we will use this library to generate the HTML of the views.
2. Add a reference to the MVC application as if you were referencing a DLL.
3. Right click the MVC project reference and select `View in Object Browser` from context menu. Your views will be within the `ASP` namespace. Please note the name of the view.
4. Create an instance of your view as shown in *Usage* below and you are done. For example, my view's name was `_Views_Test_Index_cshtml`.

As you can see most of the above steps are just setup.

**Usage**

I did a quick test and this was all the code I needed:

```
var view = new ASP._Views_Test_Index_cshtml();
view.ViewBag.Model = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };
var html = view.RenderAsHtml();
```

Since the `View.Model` is readonly, I used `ViewBag.Model` to set the model for the view. And here is the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var MyModel = this.ViewBag.Model as List<string>;
}

@for (int i = 0; i < MyModel.Count ; i++)
{
    <label>@MyModel[i]</label>
}
```

And here is the generated HTML:

```
<label>One</label>
<label>Two</label>
<label>Three</label>
```

You can pass whatever you need in `ViewBag` to your view. You may find [this article](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html) helpful.

Comment: Thanks Yoshi for detailed answer. Looks like your approach is good for creating web projects, but I need just create a few big html files. For now it seems to me excessive and unreasonable to add a new entity in project for this purpose, so I'd like to find any solution with pure dotnet.

Comment: @vladimir No it is not for creating a web project. It is using the MVC framework to generate the file for you. It is not excessive either; it took me 5 mins to do it. How is it excessive?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try to play with it and give a feedback

Comment: I am going to try this using .Net Core.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, Thanks for this solution. view.RenderAsHtml();  does not apply CSS, is there any way to make it work  please ?

Comment: @NTinkicht The CSS should be applied by the client (browser) during rendering.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, when I save the html variable you've created by doing html.Save(), on the disk, I see only the HTML page, without the src folder for JS and CSS :( maybe I'm doing it all wrong ?

My goal is to save this page on a disk and then convert it to a PDF page, The PDF conversion system works fine, I'm just struggling with the fact that my saved page has no CSS or JS :(

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for an answer to this question as well, and none of the solutions appealed to me. I therefore wrote my own library, which is used by some solutions in the two companies I've worked for lately.

Most proposed solutions are either building the strings yourself, or using libraries that you may not want to depend on (e.g. Razor).

Allow me to humble recommend my own library :)

- open-source (MIT)
- dependency-free (so can be used in any .Net Core project, standalone library, web-app, console app)
- has a pretty decent DSL-like syntax, as well as normal syntax (like `new A(myHref)`)
- creates an in-memory graph of HTML objects, which can be created and manipulated like normal C# objects, or converted to a string (with encoding etc)
- can serialize to html or to xml (xhtml-like), if you need that

Example:

```
   var fruits = new[] { "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry" };
   var html =
        _<Html>(
            _<Head>(
                _<Title>("Hello, World!")
            ),
            _<Body>(
                _<H1>("Hello, World!"),
                _<P>(
                    _("This is a paragraph with <>. "), // Becomes plain text, not an element. Text is escaped. 
                    _<Ul>(
                        fruits.Select(_<Li>)
                    )
                ),
                _UNSAFE("This will not be <b>escaped</b>") // Allows any HTML, don't use this with untrusted content. 
            )
        );
   string actualHtmlString = html.ToHtml();
```

For more documentation, source code, and usage instructions, see:

https://github.com/narve/DV8.Html
or
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DV8.Html