# Store large strings in C# (html/xml/js etc)

Tags: c#, html, string

Wanted to ask this question in scope of [Generating HTML page in C# - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774899/generating-html-page-in-c-sharp-best-practices) , but better to split it into separate question.

In my code I have to use a large text strings for generating html page, like parts of html page, css styles, javascripts etc.
 There 2 options to store it outside main code class:

**1) Store all big static strings in outside class**

Benefits:

- Main code is cleaner, but all strings are still in project's code.

Drawbacks:

- All special chars should be escaped
- Format & indents and not obvious
- Hard to check html/css/js syntax in c# code.

**2) To create a separate files for each text part (css, js, html)**

Benefits:

- Pure and maintainable html/js/css code in each file
- No need to escape special chars
- Clean formatting

Drawbacks:

- Need to read files during code execution - not sure it's a good idea.
- Possible file locks during code execution

What could you suggest to store such strings? What is the best practice?

Comment: I think it's better to store them as txt files and read them in execution time which will make them easier to edit later or change them simply without rearrange the text from scratch in ur editor and remove the escape chars and rewrite them again.

Comment: I think the best answer depends on more background like how is the application deployed? Is it a web app? Desktop app? Etc.. With that said, IMO, reading the content from files sounds generally better than maintaining strings but any answer to this question risks being pretty opinionated.

Comment: Your original linked question already gave you _opinions_ and suggestions. Don't reinvent the wheel - unless your use case demands so which doesn't seem so. You have a basic app that you trapped yourself in by saying "single page" - why? And even if it were a single page you can look into web services/Ajax (SPA, React, Angular, etc) to handle your "views" (broad subjects for this format unfortunately)

Comment: EdSF, you are talking about a new "wheel", but I still can't understand what the standard common approach for storing strings with html/css/xml content - files or strings in code...